# What does my ACF test tell me about numbers to use in ARMA?

Tags: arima, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test, acf-pacf

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxADc.jpg)

I want to use an ARMA model for seasonally adjusted quarterly GDP growth figures and then check for structural breaks. I've run an ACF, PACF, kpss and adf test on the data I have, and you can see the results from R in the imgur link above. What does it tell me about what numbers to use in my arma model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ARMA$(p,q)$ processes, the PACF will decay geometrically for
large arguments, not more can be said about it. Hence, the exact lag
order $q$ cannot be determined from the empirical PACF directly. Similarly, the population ACF decays geometrically, otherwise not much can be said. Thus, $p$ cannot be determined directly from the sample ACF. You can however determine the order of AR$(p)$ or MA$(q)$ processes by looking at the PACF or ACF in spirit of Box and Jenkins.

The best strategy is to test down from high numbers for $p$ and $q$ using the AIC or BIC, whichever is more suitable for your purposes. AIC gives you the best forecasting model, whereas BIC tends to select the correct model.

The ADF test checks for unit roots, make sure you're using the correct version of it. There is a DF-$\mu$ and a DF-$\tau$ test. Please make sure you add a self-learning tag too. I wouldn't advise you to use the kpss-test because of its null of stationarity.